# Using $_GET[...] in drupal-7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I could not find a very proper title for my problem.

I have been trying to incorporate a beautiful search bar(http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput) in my drupal website. For this to happen I need to create a php callback function, that should be like: www.mysite.com/search/callback?q=var1.

This is a prerequisite and I cannot do otherwise. However, in drupal you set up the Urls in similar to www.mysite.com/search/callback/var1.

Is there a way to achieve the first one in Drupal?

Thanks :-)

EDIT-1:
What I have already done is :

```
$items['search/callback'] = array(
      'title'             => 'Search for String',
      'description'       => 'callback function for search bar',
      'page callback'     => 'search_callback',
      'access callback'   => TRUE,
      'type'              => MENU_CALLBACK,
)
```

Comment: axmm I think it is a rather specific question. "Is there a way to achieve the first one in Drupal?".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can recomend you to explore full example for jQuery UI Autocomplete taxonomy terms here: http://xandeadx.ru/blog/drupal/526. It's originally written in Russian but you can easily read code listings and download [packed project](http://xandeadx.ru/sites/default/files/files/jqueryui_autocomplete.rar). I think you can use the same idea of module.
Some notes:

1. You can't use `q` get param for your purpose because it is used by Drupal internally. In jQuery Tokeninput you can set another name of param with `queryParam` option.
2. I recommend to check any `$_GET` param with [check_plain()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/check_plain/7).

Comment: wonderful input kalabro! I will for use you references!